# How to debug an empty LINQ result query?

Tags: c#, mongodb, linq, mongodb-.net-driver, nosql

I've added a query to my repository, that queries for a list of orders that match the email search key. But when I step through the method, my result is null although the email string matches the email stored in my orders database document, `"email": "brianvarley@gmail.com"`

I'm using the [MongoDB.Net driver](https://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/drivers/csharp/) to communicate with the MongoLabs repository. My other queries to query all documents works so doesn't seem to be a connection issue.

[image: debug result]

I tried hovering over `c.Email`, to check the database result, but no values pop up.

Does anyone know how I can debug the null result further?

This is the method that queries orders by email:

```
    public async Task<List<OrderModel>> GetAllByEmailAsync(string email)
    {
        if (orderList == null)
            await LoadDbAsync();
        return orderList.Where(c => c.Email == email).ToList();
    }
```

I added a dump to check orderList contents, but that shows a count = 0:

```
string dump = string.Join(",", orderList.ToString());
```

This is the `LoadDBAsync()`, when I step through the code, this method is skipped as OrderList isn't null:

```
    public async Task LoadDbAsync()
    {
        var orderCollection = StartConnection();

        try
        {
            orderList = await orderCollection.Find(new BsonDocument()).ToListAsync();

        }
        catch (MongoException ex)
        {
            //Log exception here:
            MessageBox.Show("A connection error occurred: " + ex.Message, "Connection Exception", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Warning);
        }
    }
```

And the `StartConnection()` called from LoadDbAsync:

```
    public IMongoCollection<OrderModel> StartConnection()
    {

        var client = new MongoClient(connectionString);
        var database = client.GetDatabase("orders");
        //Get a handle on the customers collection:
        var collection = database.GetCollection<OrderModel>("customer_orders");
        return collection;
    }
```

Comment: Could you provide a dump of `orderList` ?

Comment: Yes, how do I code that? orderList.log?

Comment: Something like `string.Join(",", orderList.ToArray())`

Comment: It may be not related to your question but you should use  `c.Email.Equals(email,StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)` (or another StringComparison value if you don't need case sensitivy) instead of `==` for strings.

Comment: @BenjaminBaumann, MongoDB doesn't really support case-insensitive searches without a large execution overhead.

Comment: Can you post `LoadDbAsync` method

Comment: @BenjaminBaumann why would he needs Equals if he doesn't care about case ?

Comment: Posted LoadDbAsync method, but that doesn't seem to be the issue as the call to that method is skipped on checking the orderList is null. @IvanStoev

Comment: If your code is deployed to a server with a different culture as the one you use while developing for example. There are subtilities in string comparison that are not covered by `==` so I think it's always a good choice to use Equals instead of `==`, see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringcomparison.aspx

Comment: @Thomas I added a line to create a dump of the orderList using ToString, but the list is null. I tried using ToArray and got the following error: http://hastebin.com/fabinupeve.vhdl

Comment: @BenjaminBaumann ok I'll try .Equals instead, didn't think of that.

Comment: @BrianJ if the list is null it isn't about .Equals.

Comment: Try with `if (orderList == null || orderList.Count() == 0)` to force reload if the list is empty

Comment: Okay so debugged the method again after adding `if (orderList == null || orderList.Count() == 0)` turns out the list was null, and load wasn't being called prior to the check. @Thomas you can add that as a solution if you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your list isn't `null` but is empty, it will never return anything... Change your code for:

```
public async Task<List<OrderModel>> GetAllByEmailAsync(string email)
{
    if (orderList == null || orderList.Count() == 0)
        await LoadDbAsync();
    return orderList.Where(c => c.Email == email).ToList();
}
```